# How to configure JSME (chemistry portal configured with javascript) in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, frontend

I want to use this JSME chemistry portal in my Vuejs application.

The first time a user loads the page, the following error appears:

```
JSME initialization error: HTML id jsme_container not found.
```

But after a refresh, it works. How can I overcome this issue?

A sample page can be found below for you to inspect:

https://peter-ertl.com/jsme/JSME_2017-02-26/jme_examples/jme_example1.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until de jsmeApplet is loaded

```
function jsmeOnLoad() {

    //Instantiate a new JSME:
    //arguments: HTML id, width, height (must be string not number!)

    jsmeApplet = new JSApplet.JSME("jsme_container", "800px", "480px", {
         "options" : "oldlook,star,atommovebutton,hydrogens"
    });




}
```

Comment: JSME initialization error: HTML id jsme_container not found." same issue. the thing is..it won't load when the page is initialized. Placed the code in the index file. how can I solve this issue?  Doing it on vuejs.